# MVC - How do I stop some links getting registered with Search Engines?

Tags: model-view-controller, seo

My site has links like this on the front page:

`www.xxx.com/user/account/register`

Can someone tell me how I can stop these links to be registered with a search engine?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `rel="nofollow"` in the link.  Google will not index this link (but will follow it).

Other search sites are not as consistent in this, but most should skip indexing this link.

Answer (score 1):

If these links are to your own pages you can create a robots.txt and put it in your root directory.
This is what I use for my personal site:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /blog
Disallow: /dev
Disallow: /apps
```

The first line,User-agent designates what kind of search engines/agents are you targeting(in my case ALL search engines). The rest are Disallow rules on which directories/files I tell them NOT to index.

More info on [robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html), or Google robots.txt.